Quick access to 'invited' or 'watched' repository
When using GitHub, I frequently run into the needs of accessing a repository I'm invited to.
But those repos aren't automatically placed under my 'Your repositories' tab, and even if I use the 'watch' function, I still can't find a place where I can access that repo.
It seems the only way to quickly access a repo in GitHub is to 'star' it?

if you were invited i think the repository is not yours, so you don't see it in your repositories

I'm not aware of any such view in the GitHub web UI, but you can get the list using GitHub's API… either by using the REST endpoint List repositories for the authenticated user (setting the affiliations parameter to a value that doesn't include owner, such as collaborator,organization_member), or using the GraphQL API with a query such as this one:

You can try it in the explorer here: https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer

query ReposNotOwned($cursor: String) {
  viewer {
    repositories(
      affiliations: [COLLABORATOR, ORGANIZATION_MEMBER]
      first: 100
      orderBy: {field: UPDATED_AT, direction: DESC}
      after: $cursor
    ) {
      totalCount
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      nodes {
        name
        owner {
          login
        }
        stargazerCount
        createdAt
        pushedAt
        updatedAt
        url
      }
    }
  }
}



It seems the only way to quickly access a repo in GitHub is to 'star' it?

GitHub also has a repository "list" feature (announcement here). It's still in public beta (at the time I composed this answer). This should be more convenient than a global list of starred repositories.
